# including linux headers in c program throwing errors for not finding headers

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile

I am compiling small program with couple of header files and a source file. the code is here

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10/source/tools/testing/selftests/net/psock_tpacket.c

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10/source/tools/testing/selftests/kselftest.h

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10/source/tools/testing/selftests/net/psock_lib.h

It needs kernel header files so  I tried something like this

```
 # gcc -I//usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-kali7-common/include psock_lib.h kselftest.h psock_tpacket.c -o t.o -I.
```

But AM getting compilation errors like this

> psock_lib.h:50:24: error: array type has incomplete element type ‘struct sock_filter’
> 1 ⨯
> there are number of these errors.

above error simply simply thrown because `struct sock_filter` not found which exists in linux headers

in my usr/src/ directory

I have `linux-headers-5.10.0-kali7-common` & `linux-headers-5.10.0-kali7-amd64`

in gcc command I am specifying `-I/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-kali7-common/include` is this correct?

both `linux-headers-5.10.0-kali7-common/include` and `linux-headers-5.10.0-kali7-amd64/include` have  makefile

Comment: The linux headers are normally in `/usr/include`. You don't normally include the headers from the source. If you want to use headers from a version other than the installed one, you need to build those first.

Comment: @EmanuelP I tried this `gcc -I//usr/include psock_lib.h kselftest.h psock_tpacket.c -o t.o -I.` but throwing same error. any idea?

Comment: Which kernel headers do you need?  All of the `#include ...` lines I could find in the code refer to files that should be available under `/usr/include` .

Comment: Why are you specifying headers in the compiler command line?

Comment: @666 Wait.. Are you trying to compile headers? Just use `gcc psock_tpacket.c`

Comment: @G.M. then how exactly I compile the code those three files with gcc

Comment: Start by trying just `gcc -o t.o psock_tpacket.c` .

Comment: Is what you get when making things more complicated than they are :)